# about simple non-abelian 2-generated group

Tags: gr.group-theory, examples

Does there exist a simple non-abelian 2-generated group $G$ and two elements $a, b \in G$, such that $\langle \{a, b\} \rangle = G$, $a^2 =1$ and $\forall c, d \in G$ $\langle \{c^{-1}bc, d^{-1}bd \} \rangle \neq G$?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600219/does-there-exist-a-two-generated-simple-non-abelian-group-with-specific-properti

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Note that $\langle b ,a^{-1}ba \rangle$ is normalized by $b$, and by $a$. Hence 
$\langle b, a^{-1}ba \rangle$ is normalized by $\langle a,b \rangle = G$. Since $G$ is simple non-Abelian, $G = \langle b, a^{-1}ba \rangle .$

Comment: Why $\langle b ,a^{-1}ba \rangle$ is normalized by $b$ ?

Comment: Any subgroup $H$ containing an element $b$ of an overgroup $G$ is certainly normalized by $b$ since $b^{-1}Hb = H$ (since $b \in H$).

Comment: also we must show why $\langle b, a^{-1}ba \rangle \neq \{1\} $ ?  I think because $ b \neq 1$.

Comment: Yes, it is of course since $b \neq 1$, but this is clear since $G \neq \langle a \rangle$ (for $G$ is assumed non-Abelian simple).

Comment: or If we show  for every $n \in \mathbb{N} , b^n \neq 1$ then our subgroup is not identity?

Comment: That would show that $b$ has infinite order, which need not be the case.